# Resolving type in referenced .NET assembly

Tags: c#, .net, compiler-errors, assembly-resolution, .net-client-profile

I'm unable to reference certain types in a separate assembly.  The strange thing is that, when I browse the referenced assembly in the object model, I can see the type I'm looking for there.  But when I try to reference the type, the compiler gives me "the type or namespace name cannot be found".

More strange facts:

- I can reference another type in the same assembly and namespace
- I can reference the missing type from another assembly (an MVC project, the project in question is a C# Windows service)

Does anyone have an idea what might be going on?

**UPDATE**

I just noticed that if I remove the dependency library reference, them re-add it, the type references immediately resolve.  But then, when I try to build the dependent project, it again says the references cannot be found.

Here are the classes

*Dependency Library Project*

```
namespace LibProject
{
    public class HelloWorld {}
}
```

*Dependent Project*

```
namespace MyProject
{
    public class HelloTest
    {
        LibProject.HelloWorld test;   // Type or namespace name could not be found
    }
}
```

**END UPDATE**

Comment: Please show an outline of the classes, public/private modifiers and using directives.

Comment: Which framework are you targeting? I had a similar problem once where the class wasn't in the Client Profile, but it *was* in the full framework (same version number, sans "Client Profile").

Comment: I've had similar issues where the Visual Studio intellisense or something wasn't updating and picking up my changes.  I ended up having to wipe out all the compiled DLL files in the various bin directories and restart Visual Studio for them to be picked up again.  Also have a similar issue where I have the same classes but built for multiple platforms within the same solution; had to close the opened files and re-open them in context of the platform I'm currently coding in.

Comment: @Jeff E, I think you might have it.  My dependent project was targeting the Client Profile, but the library project was targeting the full framework ..

Comment: @JeffE that fixed my issue, thank you.  Could you add as an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Which framework are you targeting? I had a similar problem once where the class wasn't in the Client Profile, but it was in the full framework (same version number, sans "Client Profile").